# Autogenerated Java classes from XML in Eclipse and C#

Tags: java, c#, xml, eclipse, auto-generate

I am currently working with the library [Traci4J](https://github.com/egueli/TraCI4J) and I am trying to understand its way of operation. I am doing pretty well but there is something I just don't understand.

As far as I can reach, there are different classes of type TraciObject, such as Vehicle, Lane, Route, etc... However, I was not able to find these classes among all the .java files so I when check the [issues in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/egueli/TraCI4J/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=) (I actually posted one, but nobody answered yet).

Then I found this [thread](https://github.com/egueli/TraCI4J/issues/13), where the author says the following, when another user asked about the Vehicle class:

*"Hi,
that class (and others) is auto-generated. Starting from commit 1583a24 (currently in master), if you open the library in Eclipse as a project, it should generate that class automatically. If that doesn't happen, please provide me any information that may be useful: errors, console logs...
You can also get the auto-generation by running Ant on the library's main directory"*

My question is, where can I find information about this autogeneration? I only know that there are some [XML files](https://github.com/egueli/TraCI4J/tree/master/src/xml) with the names of these auto-generated classes,  Because I am trying to do something similar in C# (actually I would only need the Vehicle class) but I don't have any clue of how to do it! I tried to generate the .cs file from the .xml file (previously generating a .xsd) but the [generated code](http://pastebin.com/9UQPvQVN) doesn't look really good...

Comment: https://github.com/egueli/TraCI4J/blob/master/pom.xml#L242 uses http://xsltmp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have been looking into that webpage, but I don't get to undestand how this really works. Should I download something?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't look into that webpage. But if you want to do something similar with C#, I'd look for a template engine that works with C# build tools, this one is for maven which to my knowledge doesn't build C# applications.